# Disable grunt uglify to remove global variables in file

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am using grunt-contrib-uglify to minify my js file. How do i configure my grunfile so that on minification global variables defined on the top of the file are not removed.

this is current uglify configuration

```
    uglify: {
            options: {
                global_defs: {
                    DEBUG: false
                }

            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= webApp.dist %>/app/static/scripts/app.js': ['<%= webApp.dist %>/app/static/scripts/*.js']

                }
            }
        },
```

this is the very top of app.js that i am trying to minify.

```
sArray = new Array();
sidArray = new Array();
rArray = new Array();
ridArray = new Array();
fArray = new Array();
fidArray = new Array();
vArray = new Array();
vidArray = new Array();
```

Comment: Are you calling this one: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#exportall

Answer (score 0):

If global variables are declared this way

```
var variable_name;
```

then uglify doesn't remove them.

Comment: If you have more to add, please [edit] your question.